# How can i fix Pycaret installation error in kaggle?

Tags: pycaret

[image: ERROR OUTPUT]

Im working from my jobs laptop but i have the same problem with my particular computer. I cant find any solution for this! Any help? I tried installing and uninstalling pycaret and tensorflow, i tried conda and pip, and even in the kaggle notebook i have trouble.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can install it as follows. It may still show that some versions could not be resolved, but the installation will go through ok.

```
!pip install --ignore-installed pycaret
```